# How do I get the full list of files bash sourced at startup?

Tags: bash

I am trying to figure out where some problematic environment variables are coming from.  I suspect that some of the system installed bash initialization scripts have been tampered with.

How can you get the full list of files that are getting sourced by bash as it starts?

I have spent some quality time with stuff like:

```
$ strace -ofoo bash
$ grep stat foo | grep -v ENOENT | sort | uniq
```

but that is some last-resort unix hackery, and I still haven't nailed it.

Comment: `strace -ofoo bash -v`

Answer (score 1):

You can put `set -x` in your startup file where is likely that the variable comes from, for example `.profile` or `.bashrc` or a more drastic `/etc/profile`
This enable a trace of all the action done to the standand error.

Things can get very verbose, so you can redirect stderr to a file with:

```
exec 2>>/path/file.log
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that the previous dev had stuck user-specific stuff in /etc/profile, i.e. sourcing an entire catkin workspace in ~his home directory.

Comment: I upvoted but didn't accept it because it didn't actually answer the question I asked.  (you had to know the lowest filename to stick that stuff into begin with).  But maybe something along the lines of "bash -x 2>&1 | grep source" would work, although that just hangs for me.  Probably easier to remember to look for stuff in /etc/profile though.